Upload program to NodeMCU present in one network while user is present in some other network
I am doing one project where I frequently need to change the programming in NodeMCU. My NodeMCU is present in some Wifi network (say X) while I am around 50 km away from that network. Is there any way to upload program to NodeMCU from this much distance.
I searched online and found that I can user (OTA) Over the air programming to upload my code without use of cable but I need to be in same network as of NodeMCU.

see the ESP8266httpUpdate library bundled with the esp8266 Arduino platform
